# Display difficulties with Ubuntu 12.10, Dual Monitors, and ATI HD 5800

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, fglrx

I have the ubiquitous and difficult display problems. I have a very limited understanding of everything regarding graphic display mechanics, and Gnome specific terms, so please let me know if you suspect communication errors on my end. All of my applications are having their own fairly similar sets of problems.

Desktop response is laggy, generally a one second delay when I hit the pseudo-windows key, and then stuttering (frame drop?) while resuming.

Document viewer lags while scrolling in a diagonal stepped pattern, and Firefox does the same with a little 'tearing' on the steps. Terminal isn't noticeably troublesome.

My hardware is more than capable using better supported operating systems (no emotions implied).

Here is some basic information: Gnome3, gdm, and here is my
lspci -vvnn|grep -m 1 -A 70 5800

```
    02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cypress LE [Radeon HD 5800 Series] [1002:689e] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Device [174b:e177]
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 4 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 50
Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 2: Memory at fd4c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Region 4: I/O ports at be00 [size=256]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fd400000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <64ns, L1 <1us
        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
    LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fee0f00c  Data: 41b1
Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Capabilities: [150 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx_updates, radeon
```

I am ready to output more information. Is there a way to code block text without using the indent method described here? My terminal output for `/var/log/gdm/\:0.log` contains some invisible (non-whitespace/newline) characters which break the indent code block on every line. My protocol is:

```
cat /.../log > new.info 
gedit new.info
```

select all, and paste. In the preview pane, it is clear that the return key does nothing now.

Comment: Any help will elicit reciprocity.