# Troubleshooting poor performance with ATI HD 5800 GPU

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, display, performance

I am attempting again to solve problems between ATI Radeon HD 5800 series (5830) GPU and Ubuntu. Three months ago I posted: 
[Display difficulties with Ubuntu 12.10, Dual Monitors, and ATI HD 5800](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250315/display-difficulties-with-ubuntu-12-10-dual-monitors-and-ati-hd-5800) 

I have 3 months of experience to draw from. Now I can be a little more concise once I get a sense of direction.

My goal is to solve these symptoms: HD video playback stutters, and display still tears when dragging windows.

Here is a basic outline of my system:

Ubuntu 13.04

Kernel 3.8.0-20

ATI Radeon HD 5830

fglrx 9.1.11

X server 1.13.3

Gnome 3.6.3.1

Dual monitors:1080p and 720p

I am going to run the phoronix-test-suite tonight, and post the graphics specific results, to evaluate progress. I am not attached to propriatary drivers; if there is a fix, I would love to implement it.

Thank you philanthropic debuggers, I am looking forwards to finally fixing this! =)

-J

Comment: I'm not sure why the previous post of yours did not get much attention, but you might have been ok editing it instead. At any rate it also doesn't make sense to me why that log displayed radeon as being a loaded module when fglrx is active, it needs blacklisted in my system, but alas fglrx is loaded so you should be fine there. I assume you can confirm Tear Free is enabled in Catalyst>Display Options>Tear Free? And as far as performance goes, you are probably better off with fglrx as opposed to radeon free, but that is more of an opinion based on the tearing results I have seen between the 2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I dismantled all of my computers, installing GPU oriented components on what is now a Windows machine, and all networking components onto linux server, and workstation. Now I have driver support when I need it, and clean Linux for everything else.